# Javascript regexp replace newline

Tags: javascript, regex

I had

```
return value.replace("\n","<br>")
            .replace("\r","<br>")
            .replace("<br><br>","<br>");
```

which only replaced the first occurence of \n with

I found that, to replace all occurences, I should replace `String` with `/String/g`

So I did:

```
return value.replace("/\n/g","<br>")
            .replace("/\r/g","<br>")
            .replace("/<br><br>/g","<br>");
```

But it seems as if I am missing something, since nothing is replaced.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `(?:\r?\n|\r)` ?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this, but look into the CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) property, especially the `pre-wrap` and `pre-line` values.

Comment: You have to pass a regular expression, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the double quotes around the regex:

```
return value.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
        .replace(/\r/g,"<br>")
        .replace(/<br><br>/g,"<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove quotes. And by the way, you can use this single and simple regex.

Use this:

```
return value.replace(/\n|\r|<br><br>/g,"<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a literal string, don't use the quotes. This means your code becomes:

```
return value.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
            .replace(/\r/g,"<br>")
            .replace(/<br><br>/g,"<br>");
```

But with regex, you can actually make it shorter by using character classes. For instance, if `value` does not have any `<br>` initially, you can use this:

```
return value.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "<br>");
```

But if your initial code has `<br>` from the start, then you can use something more like this:

```
return value.replace(/(?:[\r\n]|<br>)+/g, "<br>");
```

---

Or perhaps maybe use definite quantifiers if you want to keep consecutive newlines:

```
return value.replace(/[\r\n]{2}/g, "<br>");
```

or

```
return value.replace(/(?:[\r\n]|<br>){2}/g, "<br>");
```